# Staging area ptotection based on ip...what if my client has a dynamic IP?

Tags: .htaccess, static-ip-address

I'm trying to put online a staging area for an upcoming website... I'd usually rather use an htaccess rule to enable only me and my client to see the website...i think is safer and you dont need to rememebr passwords and so...

but my client this time has an internet provider who doesnt give him a static ip, aparently everyday or so, his ip chamges...so i have to change my htaccess!

there is any solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have him use a dynamic DNS service like dyndns.com or no-ip.com. That way he can setup a domain name like someguy.dyndns.com which would always resolve to his ip (he'll probably need to install a small daemon/service/program to automatically update the IP though). Then you can add a rule into your .htaccess like `allow from someguy.dyndns.com`.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, dynamic IPs are very common, a lot of providers disconnect the client in intervals of 12 or 24 hours, which usually means they get a new IP assigned.

Second, just giving out a username / password combination not only seems safer, but also more hassle-free. You are about to invest time into a solution that's probably not worth it. I also don't see how you would obtain the valid IP address of the client to update your .htaccess file, apart from having the client install a service that updates a dynamic DNS entry mayb - more of a hassle than remembering a login, if you ask me.